# How to handle a trivially inapplicable/incorrect "duplicate question" flag

Tags: discussion, flags, duplicate-questions

On a topic for which I have fairly extensive experience a question has been flagged as a duplicate of another one that is for a completely separate case. A person with any experience in the field would not have made that error.

The user who made the tag was helpful enough to put a comment: so I did reply with the information about the distinction.

The concern here is that there is no ambiguity: it is a clearly completely incorrect label as opposed to most others that are relatively nuanced (or correct).  Simply put: I would like to have the flag removed. Is there a way to achieve this?

Note: the specific SOF question is not of interest to focus on (or mention here) - this is a general inquiry into approach.

Seems the public wants to see the particular question. Here it is:

[How to split a DStream given a matcher](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38579418/how-to-split-a-dstream-given-a-matcher)

In any case this inquiry has already been given a perfect (and accepted) answer  by @ShadowWizard - to explain to the closer the rationale for keeping open via comment and if no response (which is the case here) - to vote for re-opening .

Furthermore I have not paid attention to the distinction between meta.so and meta.se .  So it would be fine to have this question be moved to meta.so.

Comment: Oh i'm fine to put at meta.so . Not clear actually on the distinction.

Comment: I think as many questions as possible should be sorted out on the site-specific metas.  In this case it sounds like others on the relevant tag(s) at [so] would be quickly able to vote that question re-opened/closed as appropriate.

Comment: @PolyGeo  No quarrel with that.  I will try to move it now. Ahh I'm a super low rep user here so have no such super powers. Feel free to move it .

Comment: I'd leave it - migration is possible but I don't think there's many that would insist on it for this one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> The user who made the tag was helpful enough to put a comment

Not really. The comment is automatic, posted on behalf of the user when flagging or voting to close as duplicate.

How to handle? Simply reply to that user via a comment reply (e.g. @JonDoe) , explain why it's not a duplicate, and ask them to undo the flag or retract the close vote - both options are available.

If the user refuse, or the question ends up being closed anyway, you can then vote to reopen it yourself if you have enough reputation (3k on graudated sites), otherwise you can flag, choose "Other" and explain why it's not a duplicate, then a moderator can reopen it.

Comment: Ok did not know that option were available: I have 10K and will vote to reopen. That's the perfect procedure.  btw I had already replied to the user who had made the vote to close .

Comment: @javadba and did he agree that he made a mistake by closing?

Comment: No response from that user.  ~750 rep only .

Comment: Well, so keep track and if it's closed, cast a reopen vote. :)

Comment: I suppose *this* were considered a bad question - OP getting downvoted now ;) Gotta have a sense of humor and bit of thick skin.  Worth it though.

Comment: @javadba yeah, but downvote was undone, all good now! ;)